# How to config HTTPPlatformHandler of IIS for Server Sent Event (SSE, EventStream)

Tags: go, iis, iis-express, devops, event-stream

Currently I have program that provide SSE as a service, and I have to deploy on IIS. But its does not work correctly, 
Here is the result when I run .exe without IIS.

```
data: Hello, world
```

But when its run behind IIS, Browser was stuck on loading.
I have to flush event `Hello, world` thousand times to make IIS flush result to browser and it's flush instantly instead of incremental update like SSE use to be.

Here is my `web.config`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform processPath=".\sse_server.exe" 
          arguments="-port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -environment development" 
          stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
          requestTimeout="00:05:00" 
          stdoutLogFile=".\sse_server_log">
        </httpPlatform>
        <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="false" />
        <caching enabled="false" enableKernelCache="false" />
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Here is my `go` code

```
func SSEHello(rw http.ResponseWriter, flusher http.Flusher) {
    rw.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/event-stream; charset=utf-8")
    rw.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    rw.Header().Set("Connection", "keep-alive")
    rw.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        rw.Write([]byte("data:Hello, world\n\n"))
        flusher.Flush()
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 100)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually HttpPlatformHandler has [8kb output buffer](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/7) , so my message is not sent out immediately.

I have to change [HttpPlatformHandler to ASP.NET Core Module](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/105), 
so `web.config` must update to this.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath=".\sse_server.exe"  />
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

And to start `go` 's application as `aspNetCore` on `iis`, the application need to get environment variable name `ASPNETCORE_PORT` then start http service on that port.

```
port := os.Getenv("ASPNETCORE_PORT")
http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil)
```

That's all!